# libsdl2 package not installing on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, sdl

Tried installing the package libsdl-image-2.0-0 from a .deb, which was a missing dependency for another package. It itself also had a bunch of dependencies I had to install, but anyway, NOW when I try to install it, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/YSnuxTNB
Running Ubuntu Precise, x86_64. No idea what the problem might be. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: why not just install it with aptitude?

Comment: Can't seem to find it on aptitude.

Comment: according to this it is: https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsdl2-image-2.0-0

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks. Not really that experienced with this. Successfully installed.